# Composer, Could not find a version of package

Tags: composer-php

i  have private repository with some files that are not important now, what i want to create is package to include it to composer.json

```
{
    "name": "pm/multi-curl",
    "description": "Package to multicurl",
    "version": "master",
    "type": "library",
    "minimum-stability":"dev",
    "require": {
        "ext-curl": "^7.1"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "pm/multi-curl",
                "version": "dev-master",
                "source": {
                    "url": "git@pmgit.pm.com:dk/multicurl.git",
                    "type": "git",
                    "reference": "master"
                },
                "autoload": {
                    "psr-0" : {
                        "PM\\MultiCurl" : "src"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "dk",
            "email": "dk@example.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

but when i execute `composer require pm/multi-curl` composer gives me this message `Could not find a version of package pm/multi-curl matching your minimum-stability (stable). Require it with an explicit version constraint allowing its desired stability.` i tried to change stability to dev but that didn't help at all. I also tried to do it with composer.json that looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "pm/multi-curl",
    "description": "Package to multicurl",
    "version": "master",
    "type": "library",
    "minimum-stability":"dev",
    "require": {
        "ext-curl": "^7.1"
    },
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "dk",
            "email": "dk@example.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

pmgit.pm.com is gitlab and to inform you when i execute `composer search performance-media/multi-curl` it returns correct description. What i do wrong.

Comment: Have you tried tagging a version of your package?

Comment: How to do it? In repository

Comment: Yes. Create a tag using your version control system

Comment: i added tag using `git` but still I got error that composer cannot find version with stability (stable)

Answer (score 2):

do you can use the master branch by

```
composer require pm/multi-curl:dev-master
```